# Hibernate second level cache - print result

Tags: hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I defined a second level cache in my application using @Cache annotation

I am using findById query, as the following:

```
  long id = 4;    
        Company cmp = companyDAO.findById(id);
```

Where Company is the object that I get from the DB.

How can I check if the Company object came from the DB or from the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [HitCount and/or MissCount](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/stat/SecondLevelCacheStatistics.html) API.

Something like this.....

```
int oldMissCount = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getMissCount();
int oldHitCount = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getHitCount();

 long id = 4;    
 Company cmp = companyDAO.findById(id);

 int newMissCount = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getMissCount();
 int newHitCount = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getHitCount();
 if(oldHitCount+1 == newHitCount && oldMissCount+1 == newMissCount) {
    logger.debug("came from DB");
   }  else if(oldHitCount+1 == newHitCount && oldMissCount == newMissCount) {
    logger.debug("came from cache");
}
```

Comment: i tried this code, however misscount and hit count is always returned 0...any mistakes which i could have made ??

Comment: @Anand are you sure you have enabled hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache, hibernate.cache.use_query_cache, hibernate.generate_statistics? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional

Comment: how to find out the region name (rName) for an entity?

Comment: String[] names = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames();
  
  for (String name : names) {
   logger.debug("Entity/Region Name: " + name);
  }

Answer (score 8):

> How can I check if the Company object came from the DB or from the cache?

Hibernate uses a specific category to *Log all second-level cache activity*. The relevant category  is `org.hibernate.cache`, just enable *debug* for it in the configuration of your logging framework.

See [Chapter 3.5 Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging).

Comment: I don't want to run it in a log - I want to run it in a test page that will print to the screen:
Company is cached/not cached

Comment: @Odelya: Maybe, but you're not the OP :) Just post a more specific question if this one doesn't fulfill your needs.

Comment: Hi!
I am with Riki in the same team.And I can't change her question:(
She wrote the page that needs to check if the objects in the system are cached or not.
But we don't want to use log - we want to print it the view (we use JSF)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on cache logging.