# problem in determining whether second level cache is working in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I am trying to use ehcache in my project.. i have  specified the following properties in hibernate config file -

> config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class","org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
>                   config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path","ehcache.xml");
>                   config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","true");
>                   config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","true");

Now i am still not sure whether the results are coming from DB or the cache..

I looked around and found - [Hibernate second level cache - print result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156133/hibernate-second-level-cache-print-result)  where the person is suggesting HitCount/Misscount API's

However when i tried using it the hitcount and miss count is always returned 0... here's my code

> String rName = "org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache";
>    Statistics stat =
>   HibernateHelper.getInstance().getFactory().getStatistics();
>   long oldMissCount =
>   stat.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getMissCount();
>   long oldHitCount =
>   stat.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getHitCount();
>   UserDAO user = new UserDAO();
>   user.read(new Long(1)); long
>   newMissCount =
>   stat.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getMissCount();
>   long newHitCount =
>   stat.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(rName).getHitCount();
>
> if(oldHitCount+1 == newHitCount &&
>   oldMissCount+1 == newMissCount) {
>     System.out.println("came from DB"); }
>   else if(oldHitCount+1 == newHitCount
>   && oldMissCount == newMissCount) {
>   System.out.println("came from cache");
>   }

Please let me know if i am using it wrong.. and what should be the rName(region Name) in this case..

Is there any other way of determining whether the second level cache is working ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable statistics collection:

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
```

Comment: i hav also set that property... but still the hit count is not increasing.. its still 0.. anything else which i might have missed ?

Comment: @Juzer: Try to call `getStatistics().logSummary()`. Are other values not-0?